# system component model win32 exception: Source Tree error

Tags: git, ssl, atlassian-sourcetree

**system component model win32 exception: The system can not find the specified abort : 
error [SSL:Certificate_Verify_Failed] Certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590) fatalrepository 'URL' not found**

I've created a new repository and now I am trying to clone it in source tree, I am getting above error

When I try cloning this to local folder, I am getting the error as This is not a valid source path or URL

Source Tree version: 1.9
OS: Windows Server 2008
Repo: Git

I have tried disabling the SSL certificate validation
Tried using Use Embedded Git and Use System Git Option, Really appreciate your help in resolving this error
 Corresponding ticket raised to Atlassian: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7616

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this person had a similar issue. You could try this:

> Go to Tools > Options > Git, and note whether you are using system or
>   embedded Git, and whether you have an option to install an embedded
>   Git.
>
> Prior to the issue, my SourceTree was using the embedded Git so all I
>   had to do to fix the issue was by downloading and installing Git.
>   Thank you very much for your answer!

Taken from:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/System-ComponentModel-Win32Exception-The-System-cannot-find-the/qaq-p/295635

Comment: Worked 100% for me. Just note that you go to restart Source Tree

Comment: Worked 100% for me. You saved enormous time. Please mark this as ans.